# Effects on pressure on reverse electrolysis

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, electrolysis, pressure

I am interested in the effects on pressure of the following reaction.

$$\ce{O2 + 4H+ + 4e- → 2H2O}$$

I have been trying to find data on this for a while, and I am sure that the information exists, but I haven't been able to find it. I need the math for the effects of pressure on the speed and energy output for this as the inverse of the electrolysis reaction. I can find data on electrolysis, but this seems to be more niche, if you know, or know an article that addresses this, can you please inform me if nothing exists? Is there some simple methodology that I am simply missing?

Comment: It's just a fuel cell, you likely didn't use the right keywords.

Comment: While it is related, it isn't explicitly about hydrogen fuel cells. Anyways, there are no tags relating to hydrogen fuel cells, to my knowledge.

Comment: $$E_\ce{O2/H2O} = E_\ce{O2/H2O}^\circ + \frac{RT}{4F} \ln{\left(p_\ce{O2} \cdot a_{\ce{H+}}^4\right)}$$

Comment: Follow up, can you confirm that this would say that the amount of energy released would decrease as the pressure increases?

Comment: No, I refute that statement. The potential of the oxygen cathode increases with oxygen pressure. As the used anode has probably lower potential (be aware it is a galvanic mode), the voltage of the cell increases with oxygen pressure. And provided energy for a given exchanged charge is proportional to this voltage.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the equation in a strange [at least to me] manner. Lets deconvolute. This seems to be a reaction of O2 and H2 to give water in a galvanic cell. At the anode, oxidation: H2 = 2H+ + 2e-; at the cathode, reduction: 1/2O2 +2H+ +2e- = H2O. Add the oxidation and reduction half equations to get:

H2 +1/2O2 +2H+ +2e- = H2O + 2H+ +2e-; H2 + 1/2O2 + 2H+ = H2O + 2H+.  The electrons have flown out the wire hopefully doing some work. H+ is a reactant at the cathode and a product at the anode.

The cell potential is the sum of the two half reaction potentials. These potentials are calculated from E[0] values [these can be looked up] modified for nonstandard conditions by the Nernst Equation. Detailed instructions can be found in any Physical Chemistry textbook. I left the H+ on both side of the equation because it is both a reactant and a product and since the cathode and anode are separated in space that means there is possibility of manipulation. H2 and O2 are reactants, an increase in either of their pressures should increase cell potentials and rates barring physical constraints in cell construction etc. Changes in H+ could be more complicated because cathode and anode mechanisms are different.

Comment: I do not see any issues with the way OP has written their equation, I do have to comment on the formatting of your reaction equations as they are a bit hard to read.

Comment: OP is conflating electrode reactions and overall chemistry in a manner that prevents OP from answering their own question. My equations are clear.